# How to do this Sql query in MongoDB

Tags: sql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have Two collections: **Users And Notifications**.
I need to get list of notifications of all admin users

I'm coming from a sql context. So in mssql I was able to do:

```
SELECT notificationId, notificationText  FROM notifications 
WHERE username IN (select username from users where userrole = 'admin');
```

I tried the following in mongodb:

```
db.notificaitons.find({ username: {$in:{/*get list of admin users here*/} }}, 
{notificationId: 1, notificationText: 1})
```

Is there any way to do it in a single db query? or shall I to do it in two different query.
(I'm using node js with mongoose)

I could't really get the logic. Thanks.

Comment: It requires two queries. One for admins, and second for notifications. Cache the list of admins if possible and necessary.

Comment: To be able to this as a single query you would need to store the data you want to query against with the notification, so in this case maybe the user role and name. Then you could do a query as follows: `db.notificaitons.find({ userrole: "admin" }}, 
{notificationId: 1, notificationText: 1})`

Comment: Good answers, but... Answers should be posted as *answers*, not as *comments.*

Answer (score 0):

You require either two queries, or a modification to your schema. I would recommend that you store in your notifications collection not only the `username`, but also the `userrole`:

```
{
   username: "derickr",
   userroles: [ "admin", "newbie" ].
   notificationId: 42,
   notificationText: "This is awesome",
}
```

As you can see I made userroles an array, with more than one user role - I am stipulating that this is what you have as well. Queries can now easily be done to find all notifications by admin users with:

```
// create index
db.notifications.ensureIndex( { userroles: 1 } } );

// do query
db.notifications.find( { userroles: "admin" } );
```